# How to save downloaded file when running spider on Scrapinghub?

Tags: python, scrapy

The `stockInfo.py` contains:

```
import scrapy
import re
import pkgutil

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stockInfo"
    data = pkgutil.get_data("tutorial", "resources/urls.txt")
    data = data.decode()
    start_urls = data.split("\r\n")

    def parse(self, response):
        company = re.findall("[0-9]{6}",response.url)[0]
        filename = '%s_info.html' % company
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

To execute the spider `stockInfo` in window's cmd.

```
d:
cd  tutorial
scrapy crawl stockInfo
```

Now all webpage of the url in `resources/urls.txt` will downloaded on the directory `d:/tutorial`.

Then to deploy the spider into `Scrapinghub`,and run `stockInfo spider`.

[image]

No error occur,where is the downloaded webpage?
How the following command lines executed in `Scrapinghub`?

```
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

How can i save the data  in scrapinghub,and download it from scrapinghub when job is finished?

To install scrapinghub at first.

```
pip install scrapinghub[msgpack]
```

Rewrite as `Thiago Curvelo` say,adn deploy it in my scrapinghub.

```
Deploy log location: C:\Users\dreams\AppData\Local\Temp\shub_deploy_yzstvtj8.log
Error: Deploy failed: b'{"status": "error", "message": "Internal error"}'
    _get_apisettings, commands_module='sh_scrapy.commands')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 148, in _run_usercode
    _run(args, settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 103, in _run
    _run_scrapy(args, settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 111, in _run_scrapy
    execute(settings=settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 148, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 243, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 330, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/app/__main__.egg/mySpider/spiders/stockInfo.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name ScrapinghubClient
{"message": "shub-image-info exit code: 1", "details": null, "error": "image_info_error"}
{"status": "error", "message": "Internal error"}
```

The requirements.txt contains only one line:

```
scrapinghub[msgpack]
```

The  scrapinghub.yml  contains:

```
project: 123456
requirements:
  file: requirements.tx
```

Now deploy it.

```
D:\mySpider>shub deploy 123456
Packing version 1.0
Deploying to Scrapy Cloud project "123456"
Deploy log last 30 lines:

Deploy log location: C:\Users\dreams\AppData\Local\Temp\shub_deploy_4u7kb9ml.log
Error: Deploy failed: b'{"status": "error", "message": "Internal error"}'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 148, in _run_usercode
    _run(args, settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 103, in _run
    _run_scrapy(args, settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 111, in _run_scrapy
    execute(settings=settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 148, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 243, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 330, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/tmp/unpacked-eggs/__main__.egg/mySpider/spiders/stockInfo.py", line 5, in <module>
    from scrapinghub import ScrapinghubClient
ImportError: cannot import name ScrapinghubClient
{"message": "shub-image-info exit code: 1", "details": null, "error": "image_info_error"}
{"status": "error", "message": "Internal error"}
```

1.issue remains.

```
ImportError: cannot import name ScrapinghubClient
```

2.only python3.7 and win7 installed on my local pc,why the error info say:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
```

Is the error info on the scrapinghub(remote end)?just send to my local end to show ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write data into disk in a cloud environment isn't reliable these days since everybody is using containers and they are ephemeral.

But you could save your data using Scrapinghub's [Collection API](https://doc.scrapinghub.com/api/collections.html). 
You can use it directly through the endpoints or using this wrapper: https://python-scrapinghub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

With `python-scrapinghub`, your code would look like this:

```py
from scrapinghub import ScrapinghubClient
from contextlib import closing

project_id = '12345'
apikey = 'XXXX'
client = ScrapinghubClient(apikey)
store = client.get_project(project_id).collections.get_store('mystuff')

#...

    def parse(self, response):
        company = re.findall("[0-9]{6}",response.url)[0]
        with closing(store.create_writer()) as writer:
            writer.write({
                '_key': company, 
                'body': response.body}
            )
```

After saving something into a collection, a link will appear in your dashboard:

[image: collections]

*EDIT:*

To make sure the dependencies will be installed in the cloud (`scrapinghub[msgpack]`), add them to your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and include it in the `scrapinghub.yml` file. Eg:

```
# project_directory/scrapinghub.yml

projects:
  default: 12345

stacks:
  default: scrapy:1.5-py3

requirements:
  file: requirements.txt
```

(https://shub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html#deploying-dependencies)

Thus, scrapinghub (the cloud service) will install scrapinghub (the python library). :)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: pip install scrapinghub[msgpack]

Comment: deploy it in scrapinghub.

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name ScrapinghubClient

Comment: Oh, sure. You have to tell scrapinghub to install it. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Just edited. Try to specify the stack in the scrapinghub.yml file